# Output and Input in SML

Tags: sml, smlnj

I am trying to understand TextIO to write and read files line by line. Most resources online start without some introductory texts. I do not have any previous knowledge with file handling and no advanced knowledge with SML. I do not know how to deal with signatures if that is needed.

Any Link or detailed description would be of great help.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mabye this will help you.....

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs312/2006fa/recitations/rec09.html

Comment: What kind of type in char option?

Comment: More Elaboration would help. Like to I need to open a file to read/write?